# Galaxy Note 2 Screen Size

Tags: javascript, css, media-queries, offsetwidth

I recently ran into an issue with a media query for the Samsung Galaxy Note 2.
The spec says it is 720x1280 with a pixel ration of 2.

I have a div with a width of 100% and the .offsetWidth comes back as 541.

Can Anyone explain this?

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 0):

Do You have the user-scalable meta tags in Your website?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

I think it may be caused by adjusting to (some initial) width of website.

Hope it helps but am not sure.

Comment: I have: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />